# Rails 4 grouping duplicates

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql

I wasn't sure how to ask this question.  I am new to Ruby on Rails and am still figuring out how to piece everything together.

I have books, orders, products and users.  Within a specific view, I would like to display one product_id per user — most users will have the same product_id multiple times.

Here's my book view.

```
  <% @orders.each do |order| %>
     <% order.product.books.each do |book| %> 
        <%= link_to book.title %>
     <% end %>
  <% end %>
```

In my book controller I have

```
      def index
        @orders = Order.select(:product_id).distinct
        @books = Book.page params[:page]
      end
```

All of this works well (view shows one product_id per order product_id, even if there are duplicates) until I call order.created_at which gives a missing attribute error.  I know this error is because I am only requesting :product_id on order, but when I add :created_at `(@orders = Order.select(:product_id, :created_at).distinct)` to the select query I get duplicate :product_ids.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

Well, you have to think about what that would look like. When you are selecting rows by a distinct `product_id` you are discarding all other order rows that have the same `product_id`. But when you add `created_at` back into the mix your resulting record set will include the same `product_id` because the `distinct` is operating against the tuple of `(product_id, created_at)` instead of just the `product_id`.

Your original `@orders` isn't actually all of your orders, it's just a subset because it chose a unique one per `product_id`.

I find it helpful to append `to_sql` to the end of a query to see what the actual SQL coming out of ActiveRecord is doing:

```
> Order.select(:product_id).distinct.to_sql
=> SELECT DISTINCT "orders"."product_id" FROM "orders"

> Order.select(:product_id, :created_at).distinct.to_sql
=> SELECT DISTINCT "orders"."product_id", "orders"."created_at" FROM "orders"
```

Try running those in the database and you'll see what data ActiveRecord is using to construct ActiveRecord instances and realize that ActiveRecord is just taking whatever rows come back in the data and manufacturing objects based on that.

Comment: This makes a lot of sense.  Thank you.  Do you have a recommendation to get this to work properly?  Maybe I'm going about it the wrong way.